# Can I join two partitions located on two separate hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I would like to join two partitions located on two separate hard drives?

Is this possible?

Which tool can do this?

I am used to using Gparted.

Can it be done with with Gparted ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [mdadm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) you can create a stripe from partitions. So yes, it is possible.

You do not just use gpart though, except for setting the partition type to 0xFD.

You also want to do something like:

- `apt-get install mdadm` or `emerge mdadm` or `yum install mdadm` (or whatever your flavour of Linux uses).
- And then `mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb4` to create a single array from two partitions (in this case the second parition on the first drive and the fourth partition on the second drive).

For more information please read the man pages and make a backup before you try this. (Creating the array and formatting it will destroy any old data on it).

PS: I assumed Linux, but the same can be done on FreeBSD or with windows.

Comment: It accomplishes this on top of devices or Os only

Comment: Aye. There is nothing blocking a hardware RAID from doing the same, but most HW RAID solutions I saw seem to use whole disks only.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of system you're on, but from your mention of gparted, I'm going to assume Linux.

On Linux, combinining partitions from two separate physical disks into one logical partition is primarily a job for [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29).  It will allow you to create a logical partition that is the size of the two physical partitions combined (minus some overhead), upon which you can create a single filesystem.  LVM will allow you to later change the partition size if desired.

The [LVM HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) has extensive document, but you may prefer a
[simple intro](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/410/A_simple_introduction_to_working_with_LVM) or [beginner's guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm).

Be aware, that by linking multiple physical drives into a single logical partition, you're now increasing that filesystem's exposure to hard drive failure. (Backups are as essential as ever!).

Comment: I assumed linux for the same reason (though gpart also runs on other operating systems).